# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, Interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I know that this is one of the most encountered error but I am really struggling to get around it.
i have a property on my Controller:
    `private readonly ISelectListFactory _selectFactory;`
and a method that called to populate the viewbag
    `private void PopulateLists()
    {
            var continent = _selectFactory.GetItems();
     }` 
and the interface

```
public interface ISelectListFactory
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems();

}
```

and in the controller constructor I have the following:

```
public LocationController(ISelectListFactory selectFactory)
    {
        _selectFactory = selectFactory;
     }
```

but I am getting this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object and not sure how to overcome it.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a line of code where an instance of an object gets created and placed into `_selectFactory`?

Comment: @DavidTansey there is a method that implement the ISelectListFactory where the GetItems methods is defined, but strange enough if I put a breakpoint on GetItems, I don't get there and this is strange to me

Comment: look closely at the code in the answer of Darin below.

Comment: @DavidTansey: you are right mate thanks was blinded by the readonly property.Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have instantiated this `_selectFactory` variable somewhere. Like for example:

```
_selectFactory = new SomeConcreteSelectListFactory();
```

or if you are using dependency injection you might configure your DI framework to inject it into the constructor:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly ISelectListFactory _selectFactory;
    public HomeController(ISelectListFactory selectFactory)
    {
        _selectFactory = selectFactory;
    }

    ... some controller actions where you could use the _selectFactory field
}
```